# Netbeans in Ubuntu - Click in "New Project" and nothing happens

Tags: java, netbeans

In Netbeans IDE 8.2, I click in "New Project" and no window shows up.
The same happens when I click in "New File" (But I guess it is because there is no project open).

What could it be?
I installed Netbeans downloading `.sh` from the official website and running `sudo chmod +x <netbeans.sh>`.

I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Could you start Netbeans from commandline and check if there is some error printed. In which environment do you run Netbeans?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04. I can't start by `netbeans`. I can only start by going to the `bin/` of the installation and running `./netbeans`. Nothing shows up in terminal.

Comment: Could you, just before you try to create a project, open the Netbeans log `View -> IDE log` and check which error might be reported there.

Answer (score 3):

I encounted the same problem when I installed Netbeans 8.2 in Linux Mint 18.

From Netbeans log View > IDE, it reported this error which appears to be a known problem (Bug 258945 - ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory). I noticed the keyword specified for this issue is JDK_9.

SEVERE [global]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-ea/BuiltinClassLoader.java:366)

I went in and changed netbeans_jdkhome entry in /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/etc/netbeans.conf from java-9-oracle to java-8-oracle

netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Appending

```
-J--add-modules=java.se.ee
```

to netbeans_default_options within etc/netbeans.conf fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a solution to this problem in another thread. I was having the same problem as you. The problem you mention is with Ubuntu, but it will work for Windows as well.

The problem is just that the JDK is not compatible with the netbeans (I used version 9). It works once you reinstall Netbeans and use an older version of JDK (I use version 8).